# Component class_1 is not part of any NgModule

Tags: angular

How can I find out what is the affected component name? I really don't understand why angular says "class_1" is the component name. I'm using Angular 7.0.0 and I'm doing a refactor. (6 components into a new module)

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Component class_1 is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
Error: Component class_1 is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._createCompiledHostTemplate (compiler.js:24520)
    at compiler.js:24496
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at compiler.js:24493
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:24482)
    at compiler.js:24410
    at Object.then (compiler.js:1012)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:24409)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:24369)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._createCompiledHostTemplate (compiler.js:24520)
    at compiler.js:24496
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at compiler.js:24493
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:24482)
    at compiler.js:24410
    at Object.then (compiler.js:1012)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:24409)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:24369)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:13842)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)
```

Comment: Try recompile or provide a bit more code?

Comment: Add the `moulde` in your question - that might help us clarify some solution

Answer (score 0):

I've just resolved the problem. I removed every route in my routes file and added back one-by-one and I found out I missed 1 component from my module declaration. However I really don't understand why angular says that the component name is "class_1", but I realize that the affected component was in another module, because there was 2 component with the same name and I tried to use a wrong one. So I assume that angular cannot get the affected component name if it is in another module.